# "to" argument must be a list or tuple

Tags: django

Not sure why my contact form is not working.

When I am trying to send an message thru the contact form it is giving me an Exception Type: TypeError

It says "to" argument must be a list or tuple

If someone could explain whats the problem I would appreciate it a lot:)

This is the code:

**views.py**

```
def kontakt(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        message_name = request.POST['fname']
        message_lname = request.POST['lname']
        message_email = request.POST['eaddress']
        message_tel = request.POST['tel']
        message = request.POST['message']

        send_mail(
            message_name,
            message_lname,
            message_email,
            message_tel,
            message,
            ['mail@gmail.com'],
        )

        return render(request, 'kontakt.html', {})

    else:
        return render(request, 'kontakt.html', {})
```

**settings.py**

```
# Email Settings
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 578
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pasword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**Contact form html**

```
form action="{% url 'kontakt' %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="site-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label for="fname">Ime</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label for="lname">Prezime</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label for="eaddress">Email Adresa</label>
                    <input type="text" name="eaddress" id="eaddress" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label for="tel">Broj Tel.</label>
                    <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="message">Poruka</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Pošalji" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 px-3 px-5">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If `send_mail` in your code is [`django.core.mail.send_mail(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mail), then the method signature looks as follows:

```
send_email

send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)
```

Here `recipient_list` must be a `list` of strings.

**You have got other arguments incorrect as well.**

First argument is `subject`. You seem to be passing `from_email` .
Second argument is `message`. You are passing message as fifth argument (which actually is `fail_silently`)